# Wordpress Plugin Shortcodes

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

i would like to know, is there any way, for example `adding a shortcode`, that will let user to put my plugin's widget anywhere he wants??? 
and how can i add it to my plugin?

Please help me, if you know!

Comment: You already know what to search for. Just look in the codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Answer (score 0):

Just look in the codex for [shortcodes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API).
There is the answer to your question.

If you have any more specific questions when you're trying to add them to your plugin then ask those. Not a general one like this.